# How do I resolve whl Visual Studio installation problem

Tags: python, installation

I have attempting to install a python whl package for PyLEnM and keep receiving an error. I am using Python 3.10.1, pip 23.0, setup tools 65.5,and Visual Studio 2022. The error I receive is:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DDOCTEST_CONFIG_DISABLE -DRICHDEM_COMPILE_TIME="\"Unknown\"" -DRICHDEM_GIT_HASH="\"Unknown\"" -DRICHDEM_LOGGING -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -Ilib/ -IC:\Users\rpahy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\rpahy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc\pywrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src\pywrapper.obj -std=c++11 -g -fvisibility=hidden -O3
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-g'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fvisibility=hidden'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
pywrapper.cpp
lib/pybind11/numpy.h(35): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
lib/pybind11/numpy.h(35): error C2338: static_assert failed: 'ssize_t != Py_intptr_t'
src\pywrapper.cpp(226): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'const pybind11::ssize_t' to 'const richdem::Array3D::xy_t', possible loss of data
src\pywrapper.cpp(226): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'const pybind11::ssize_t' to 'const richdem::Array3D::xy_t', possible loss of data
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Any suggestions to resolve would be appreciated. Thanks.

Upgraded PIP and Visual Studio to latest version.

Answer (score -2):

Try to see if any files are in your bin or somewhere else. If you look at the problem you can see directories leading to /bin .

Comment: Well, he is on windows and this is not there on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked bin folder and a number of files are there including cl.exe.